# Delete empty rows of the last sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    For b = 1 To 10
        If Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range(b, 1).Value = "" Then Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(b).Delete
    Next b
End Sub
```

I am running a macro through `Module1` that generates new sheets containing extrapolated data of `Sheet1` using `Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

I am able to reference the rows of this new sheet using `Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(1)`

However, I'm unable to make `Sub DeleteEmptyRows()` work.

Comment: You can use `EntireRow` cell property, but it is not good to do it in such a loop. If you delete the row 3, the fourth becomes 3 after deletion and all below it will be messed up. You can do it in reverse order but a better solution is using a `Union` range to be filled with the necessary cells and the rows to be deleted of the code end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
   Dim b As Long, ws As Worksheet, rngDel As Range
   
   Set ws = Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    For b = 1 To 10
        If ws.Range(b, 1).Value = "" Then
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = ws.Range(b, 1)
            Else
                Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, ws.Range(b, 1))
            End If
    Next b
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bhavesh Shaha Didn't find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it work as you need? It should be very fast, even on a very large range...

Comment: I'm running into this error: Run-time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. I suspect it might have to do with it being present in `Module1`?

Comment: @Bhavesh Shaha Are there Chart sheets involved or (very) hidden worksheets? If not something confidential, can you share the workbook you try the code? Cleaning the sensitive data, if the case...